# Ionic 4 : ionic run browser give cannot get page on refreshing the page

Tags: ionic-framework, url, ionic4, hash-location-strategy

I'm getting cannot get the page on refreshing it while running **ionic cordova run browser**
 but working fine in **ionic serve**

```
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Keyboard,
    HttpService,
    HTTP,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AndroidPermissions
  ],
```

i don't want to use **HashLocationStrategy** because of hash in url

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

Comment: Which method use for page jump from one page to other? How you pass data from one page to other?

Comment: angular navigation router is used from going to one page to another and data passing i have used service and storage